# FilterOperator.Contains Doesn't work correctly

Tags: sapui5

I have a model which contains site info.

If I do a search on the beginning of the "SearchString" (using `FilterOperator.Contains`), the input list is populated fine, but if I search on a string not at the beginning of the string, nothing is returned.

e.g ... SearchString= "100 My Town"

An entry of '100' works.
An entry of 'My' doesn't !

No error is displayed either.

Controller :

```
handleSuggest: function (oEvent) {
    var sTerm = oEvent.getParameter("suggestValue");
    var aFilters = [];
    if (sTerm) {
         aFilters.push(new Filter("SearchString", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sTerm ));
    }

    oEvent.getSource().getBinding("suggestionItems").filter(aFilters);

},
```

View :

```
<Input              
                    id="shopInput"
                    type="Text"
                    placeholder="Enter Shop Number ..."
                    showSuggestion="true"
                    suggest="handleSuggest"    
                    suggestionItems="{/SiteSet}"
                    change="validateInput"
                    liveChange="liveChange"
                    valueStateText="Shop Number must be valid"
                    suggestionItemSelected="suggestionItemSelected">
                    <suggestionItems>
                        <core:Item text="{SearchString}" />
                    </suggestionItems>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: did you try using another Operator? like startsWith? Just to check if the General functionality is working?

Comment: Yeah. StartsWith is fine. Also contains returns the correct JSON from the SAP service...

Answer (score 1):

I've now found the solution from right under my nose in the input.suggestions.custom section of https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Input/samples

```
handleSuggest : function(oEvent) {
  var view = this.getView();
  var sTerm = oEvent.getParameter("suggestValue")
  view.byId("shopInput").setFilterFunction(function(sTerm, oItem) {
 // A case-insensitive 'string contains' style filter
     return oItem.getText().match(new RegExp(sTerm, "i"));
 });

},
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd an other problem with FilterOperator.Contains.

My scenarios involves:

- oData V2
- Backend Java using Olingo
- Frontend in Apache

I'd putted in my controller this Filter:

```
aFilter.push(new Filter("description", FilterOperator.Contains, `'${fDescription}'`));
```

But the filter didn't work.

Then, I'd investigated the problem and identify that FilterOperator.Contains, in  SAPUI5 framework doesn't build the query parameter right.

Because the src/sap/ui/model/odata/ODataUtils.js package on ODataUtils._createFilterSegment function doesn't included the suffix "eq true":

```
case "Contains":
        return "substringof(" + oValue1 + "," + sPath + ")";
```

Searching in odata.org (https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/) and conforming de sample:

```
$filter=substringof('Alfreds', CompanyName) eq true
```

To fix the problem I'd changed the controller to use FilterOperator.EQ in this way:

```
aFilter.push(new Filter(`substringof('${fDescription}',description)`, FilterOperator.EQ, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you are missing to set the ID in the Suggestion item, which enables you to search for it? Your Filter goes on SiteId, but your Suggestion item is only binded to SearchString.

This should help:

```
<suggestionItems>
      <core:Item key="{SiteId}" text="{SearchString}" />
</suggestionItems>
```

Comment: I've now correct the original post.   I'm not search on SiteId, I'm searching on SearchString.  However SiteId is the key in the oData, not SearchString. I've included item key ="SiteId" (above) but with no luck